# Exception when using the code from JavaBrains

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-aop

I'm learning Spring and AOP with the help of Koushik from JavaBrains. I'm at this lesson now:
http://javabrains.koushik.org/2011/08/spring-tutorial-27-writing-our-first.html
But when I try to run it, I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.koushik.javabrains.AopMain.main(AopMain.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.<init>(AbstractClassGenerator.java:38)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.<init>(KeyFactory.java:127)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:112)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.createEnhancer(Cglib2AopProxy.java:229)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy.getProxy(Cglib2AopProxy.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:476)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 11 more
```

Following are the class files and xml file used in the tutorial:

```
package org.koushik.javabrains;

import org.koushik.javabrains.service.ShapeService;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AopMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        ShapeService shapeService = ctx.getBean("shapeService", ShapeService.class);
        System.out.println(shapeService.getCircle().getName());
    }

}
```

---

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.service;

import org.koushik.javabrains.model.Circle;
import org.koushik.javabrains.model.Triangle;

public class ShapeService {
    private Circle circle;
    private Triangle triangle;

    public Circle getCircle() {
        return circle;
    }
    public void setCircle(Circle circle) {
        this.circle = circle;
    }
    public Triangle getTriangle() {
        return triangle;
    }
    public void setTriangle(Triangle triangle) {
        this.triangle = triangle;
    }
}
```

---

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.model;

public class Circle {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.model;

public class Triangle {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    @Before("execution(public String getName())")
    public void LoggingAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Advice run. Get Method called");
    }
}
```

---

spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />



    <bean name="triangle" class="org.koushik.javabrains.model.Triangle">
        <property name="name" value="Triangle name" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="circle" class="org.koushik.javabrains.model.Circle">
        <property name="name" value="Circle name" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="shapeService" class="org.koushik.javabrains.service.ShapeService" autowire="byName" />

    <bean name="loggingAspect" class="org.koushik.javabrains.aspect.LoggingAspect" />
</beans>
```

I would really appreciate any possible help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The deal was that I had a cjlib-2.2.2.jar in the AspectJ library, and cjlib-2.2.3.jar in JRE System Library. When I deleted the second one, it started to work as it suppose to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the perfect solution for this is **asm4.1.jar** is not compatible with **cglib2.2** or **cglib2.3**. Change the **asm4.1** to **asm3.x.x**.

This has worked for me.